# How can I change the color of a Google Link?

Tags: css

I am trying to build a chrome extension that changes the color of websites for colorblind people. One of the features is changing the color of links that have been clicked.

I have tried "a:visited" and it works for most links, but does not work on the actual Google search page. I tried inspecting the page and found that the links are h3 elements. I then tried using the h3 selector, but it changes the color of all of them. How can I make it so that it only changes the color of the links clicked.

[Here you can see that the clicked links are orange-brown and the other links are blue, but the website names remain black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZLSG.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Bear in mind the security/privacy issues around the `:visited` pseudo-class, which has historically been used to scrape user browsing history; see: "[Privacy and the `:visited` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector)" at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Those `h3` elements are inside `a` elements, so you can address them like this:

```
a:visited h3 {color: red;}
```